# MySQL DISTINCT not Filtering out

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the folowing sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(tbl_products.product_id), tbl_products.product_title,
            tbl_brands.brand_name, tbl_reviews.review_date_added, 
            NOW() AS time_now
            FROM tbl_products, tbl_reviews, tbl_brands
            WHERE tbl_products.product_id = tbl_reviews.product_id AND
            tbl_products.brand_id = tbl_brands.brand_id
            ORDER BY tbl_reviews.review_date_added DESC
```

That needs to filter out any duplicate product_id's unfortunatly selecting tbl_reviews.review_date_added makes each record unique which means DISTINCT will not work anymore.

Is there any otherway of doing this query so that product_id is still unique?

I did do the GROUP BY and the problem is I display the tbl_reviews.review_date_added on a website and it selects the oldest date.  I need the newest date.

Regards

Comment: What about using max(tbl_reviews.review_date_added) or min(tbl_reviews.review_date_added), you have to select one tbl_reviews.review_date_added for all tbl_products.product_id (min and max are only suggestions) otherwise it will not work (as you've noticed already).

Comment: I read this after I implemented it. It does indeed work! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinct works for the entire row.  The parenthesis are just around the field:

```
distinct (a), b, c  ===  distinct a, b, c
```

A straightforward solution is `group by`.  You can use `min` to select the oldest date.

```
select  tbl_products.product_id
,       min(tbl_products.product_title)
,       min(tbl_brands.brand_name)
,       min(tbl_reviews.review_date_added)
,       NOW() AS time_now
FROM    tbl_products, tbl_reviews, tbl_brands
WHERE   tbl_products.product_id = tbl_reviews.product_id AND
        tbl_products.brand_id = tbl_brands.brand_id
GROUP BY
        tbl_products.product_id
ORDER BY 
        min(tbl_reviews.review_date_added) DESC
```

Note that if a product can have multiple brands, this will pick the lowest one.

Answer (score 2):

With the description given, it's a bit hard to be certain, but if `review_date_added` is the only problem, it *seems* like you want the MAX() of that date?

If the following doesn't help, please could you give example data, example output, and a description of how you want the output to be created?

```
SELECT
  tbl_products.product_id,
  tbl_products.product_title,
  tbl_brands.brand_name,
  MAX(tbl_reviews.review_date_added) AS review_date_added,
  NOW() AS time_now
FROM
  tbl_products
INNER JOIN
  tbl_reviews
    ON tbl_products.product_id = tbl_reviews.product_id
INNER JOIN
  tbl_brands
    ON tbl_products.brand_id = tbl_brands.brand_id
GROUP BY
  tbl_products.product_id,
  tbl_products.product_title,
  tbl_brands.brand_name
ORDER BY
  MAX(tbl_reviews.review_date_added) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT pr.product_id, pr.product_title,
       bd.brand_name, 
      (SELECT MAX(rev.review_date_added) FROM tbl_reviews rev
       WHERE pr.product_id = rev.product_id) AS maxdate, 
       NOW() AS time_now
FROM tbl_products pr INNER JOIN tbl_reviews re 
    ON pr.product_id = re.product_id
INNER JOIN tbl_brands bd
    ON pr.brand_id = bd.brand_id
GROUP BY pr.product_id
ORDER BY re.review_date_added DESC
```

or (as suggested by @Hogan)

```
SELECT pr.product_id, pr.product_title,
       bd.brand_name, md.maxdate
       NOW() AS time_now
FROM tbl_products pr INNER JOIN tbl_reviews re 
    ON pr.product_id = re.product_id
INNER JOIN tbl_brands bd
    ON pr.brand_id = bd.brand_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id, MAX(review_date_added) AS maxdate 
            FROM tbl_reviews rev GROUP BY product_id) md
    ON pr.product_id = md.product_id
GROUP BY pr.product_id
ORDER BY re.review_date_added DESC
```

Comment: Faster to join to a sub-query of max review dates then to do a sub-query every row

Comment: @Hogan: do you think my new query is correct? I really cannot try it ;)

Comment: Looks right to me. I think it will be faster than the accepted answer.(Can't test it right now also :)

Answer (score 0):

I combined the answer of Andomar with some changes you will find here.

```
SELECT tbl_products.product_id, tbl_products.product_title,
                    tbl_products.product_date_added, tbl_brands.brand_name,
                    MAX(tbl_reviews.review_date_added) AS review_date_added, NOW() AS time_now
            FROM tbl_products, tbl_reviews, tbl_brands
            WHERE tbl_products.product_id = tbl_reviews.product_id AND
                    tbl_products.brand_id = tbl_brands.brand_id
            GROUP BY tbl_products.product_id
            ORDER BY MAX(tbl_reviews.review_date_added) DESC
```

Works beautifully and shows the newest date at tbl_reviews.review_date_added.

Regards